# Update number of rows in section asynchronously

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've been getting a table view inconsistency exception, wanting to know a way around it.
Tapping on a table view cell accessory view, I display an additional cell in the table view, think of a control panel popping below the row you're looking at. Meanwhile, an HTTP request to an API is fetching the second page of data.. if the data comes in while I'm animating the control panel, I get the crash.

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (31) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (32), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'`

Comment: Post the http callback code. Looks like it might call reloadData or something while animating

Comment: this error typically indicates that you are not managing your data source correctly and/or not calling reload data after updating it.

Comment: Yes, reloadData is being called from the http callback code while the table view is animating a new cell. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Turned out the issue wasn't in the content updates directly. I was adding a row in numberOfRowsInSection like so:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {   
    NSInteger count = [self.sharedItems count];
    if (_contentPagesTotal > _contentPagesLoaded) {
        // Add a row for the loading label
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

which is now

```
if (self.showLoadingRow) {
    count ++
}
```

And in the content http callback:
self.showLoadingRow =  _contentPagesTotal > _contentPagesLoaded

So the loading cell was sticking around when it shouldn't have.